# tf broadcasting rate

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello

im trying to increase the rate of which tf transform is being published
it seems that no matter what i do the rate stays 1 hz
even if cout prints at 10 hz, when i tf_echo the transform it still appears to be
published at 1 hz
i didnt find in ROS ANSWER any documentation about that

thanks!

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "tfpub");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Rate r(10.0);

  tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;

  while(n.ok()){
    broadcaster.sendTransform(
      tf::StampedTransform(
        tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), tf::Vector3(0.1, 0.0, 0.2)),
        ros::Time::now(),"map", "odom"));
    std::cout<< ros::Time::now() <<std::endl;
    r.sleep();
    ros::spinOnce();

  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265297/tf-broadcasting-rate/) by [alonsheader](https://answers.ros.org/users/30995/alonsheader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-07-02**:
This probably won't fix the issue, but put the `ros::spinOnce();` call before the `r.sleep();` call. You should never have anything after a `Rate.sleep()` call as this messes with loop timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rate at which tf_echo prints to the screen is a command line argument and does not reflect the underlying message rates.

If you want to determine the rate of publishing you should use tf_monitor. There's a [tutorial on debugging](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Debugging%20tf%20problems).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-07-02**:
Totally agree. The correct way to view the rate is actually using `view_frames` tool

**Comment by [alonsheader](https://answers.ros.org/users/30995/alonsheader/) on 2017-07-03**:
thank you!